# retun values in function of array.map in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Using React JSX, I have an array `levels` which can contain arrays of one or more of the levels with a name, for example: `one`, `two` and `three`. In my render function I can call `{renderLevels}` which renders all levels separated by a comma.

**This works:**

```
const renderLevels = levels.map((item, index) => {
      return (
         <Fragment key={index}>
            {(index ? ' & ' : '')} {item.name}
         </Fragment>
      )
   }
);
```

In case all levels are present I want to render 'all levels', instead of the comma separated list. In all other cases I want the list. So I change my code.

**This does not work:**

```
const renderLevels = () => {

   if (levels.length === 3) {
      return (
         'all levels'
      )
   }

   levels.map((item, index) => {
         return (
            <Fragment key={index}>
               {(index ? ' & ' : '')} {item.name}
            </Fragment>
         )
      }
   )
};
```

My `const` is now a function I then call with `{renderLevels()}`. **The problem:** the list of item names is no longer returned when there are fewer than 3 levels. My if-statement works and `console.log(item.name)` inside `.map` does show me the results in case there are fewer than 3 levels. Getting the return values however does not. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: add return in `levels.map((item, index) => {` like `return levels.map((item, index) => {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `return` for the `levels.map()`. Currently, you are just returning for the function, inside the `if` block but you have not returned anything when that `if` is not executed.

```
const renderLevels = () => {

   if (levels.length === 3) {
      return (
         'all levels'
      )
   }

   return levels.map((item, index) => {
         return (
            <Fragment key={index}>
               {(index ? ' & ' : '')} {item.name}
            </Fragment>
         )
      }
   )
};
```